# can you add values in a for loop from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a for loop looping through an array of integers. Im trying to get the sum of all of the elements in the array. Can I do this in a loop?

code below:

```
    int numOfValues;

    //prompt user for number of values
    System.out.print("How many values? ");
    numOfValues = input.nextInt();

    int[] values = new int[numOfValues];        

    for(int i=1; i<numOfValues;i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
        values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        int sum += 0 + values[i];
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
```

this line int `sum += 0 + values[i];`

Is where im trying to get all of the array element values total up but i think its wrong. its just printing out the actual numbers and not the sum.

Comment: Take that int sum outside the loop .

Comment: Array's index starts from 0, not from 1.

Answer (score 4):

declare   `int sum` out side of the for loop

i.e

```
 int sum =0;  
for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
        values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
         sum += values[i];
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
```

**Edit:** as `@Orin` pointed out

Also

start for loop with zero index

Comment: Also needs to start the `for` loop at "0" instead of "1"

Answer (score 3):

declare int sum out side of the loop

```
    int sum =0;  
for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
    {

        System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
        values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
         sum += values[i];
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Array elements start from 0 in java. So your `for` should also start with 0.
2. declare sum before the loop
3. init sum to 0 before the loop
4. print sum after the loop.

changed program

```
int numOfValues;

//prompt user for number of values
System.out.print("How many values? ");
numOfValues = input.nextInt();

int[] values = new int[numOfValues];        

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
{

    System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
    values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
    sum += values[i];
}

System.out.print(sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

**How To Fix:**

Put `sum` variable outside the loop

```
int sum = 0
for(int i = 1; i < numOfValues; i++)
{

        System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
        values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        sum += values[i];
        System.out.print(sum);
}
```

**Reason:**

The value of sum won't be stored because you define the variable every time the loop iterate. You only need to define it once and continually add values to `sum`'s value.

**Moreover:**

Since you said:

> I'm trying to get the sum of all of the elements in the array

To iterate through all elements in the array, you need to start your iteration from the starting index. The starting index of an array is `0` **not** `1`. So, you need to change this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < numOfValues; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < numOfValues; i++)
```

**Additionally, for your information**:

`sum += values[i];` is equivalent to `sum = sum + values[i];`

Comment: The loop should start at index 0, not index 1.

Comment: @eboix I was editing that. I just saw that his variable `i` starts from `1` not `0` after I posted the first version of my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your variable sum is always initialized for each loop of your array:

Try this:

```
int sum =0;  
for(int i=1; i<numOfValues;i++)
{

    System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
    values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
     sum += values[i];
    System.out.print(sum);
}
```

Comment: Primitive type don't have instances, I think you mean by initialization.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
{
    System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
    values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
    sum += values[i];
 }
 System.out.print(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare

```
sum = 0;
```

and within the loop use

```
sum += values[i];
```

Also remember that arrays start with zero.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this way please

```
   System.out.print("How many values? ");
   numOfValues = input.nextInt();
   int[] values = new int[numOfValues];        
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<numOfValues;i++)
   {
       System.out.print("Value " + i + " :");
       values[i] = input.nextInt(); 
       sum += values[i];
   }
   System.out.print(sum);
```

Comment: starting the loop with `int i=0` will give you the correct result.

Comment: Oops! Sorry its a mistake.